# Where is the leak?

Tags: iphone, uikit, core-graphics

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(targetSize); //instruments show here a leak 128bytes

CGRect thumbnailRect = CGRectZero;

thumbnailRect.origin = thumbnailPoint;
thumbnailRect.size.width  = scaledWidth;
thumbnailRect.size.height = scaledHeight;

[sourceImage drawInRect:thumbnailRect];

newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Hi I'm trying to scale a UIImage so I load it with

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];
```

and then pass it into a method. In that method I have the code above that resizes my image and at the end of the method I have a

```
return newImage;
```

The instruments show me a leak at line

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(targetSize); //instruments show here a leak 128bytes
```

What am I doing wrong? Where exactly is the leak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't appear to be doing anything wrong; it could be a bug in the `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` method. 128 bytes is kind of trivial, though—unless you're doing this thumbnail creation a huge number of times, you probably don't need to worry about it.

Comment: I'm only doing it once but it pisses me off not knowing what is wrong. Thanks for your response

Answer (score 1):

Instruments will tell you where the memory was first allocated; this apparently is in UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(). I think double-clicking the leak (or so) will list all the retains/autoreleases/releases; look in one of those.